# MATLAB: To import txt file and to remove every header after n-row then keeping the first column only

Tags: matlab, import, header

i have txt file looking like below which i need to import to Matlab and keeping only values of 'p'. However 'p' in every 'time' is stored in different column in matlab workspace. Size of 'p'for each 'Time' would be '8x1'. Thank you for any help.

---

```html
 ASCI I VARIABLES    
NB = 7    
Time 0    
IB p T S1 S2
0 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
1 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
2 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
3 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
4 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
5 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
6 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
7 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
    
Time 0.01    
IB p T S1 S2
0 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
1 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
2 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
3 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
4 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
5 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
6 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
7 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
    
Time 0.03    
IB p T S1 S2
0 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
1 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
2 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
3 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
4 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
5 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
6 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
7 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
    
Time 0.07    
IB p T S1 S2
0 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
1 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
2 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
3 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
4 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
5 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
6 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
7 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
    
Time 0.15    
IB p T S1 S2
0 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
1 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
2 394.966 343.15 0.1 0.9
3 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
4 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
5 373.745 343.15 0.1 0.9
6 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
7 363.134 343.15 0.1 0.9
```

I have tried doing it with the following code, but does not seem right.

```html
Var = 5; %number of variables
NB = 8;
t = Data (:,2); %obtained from another data, but the content is exactly as Time values 
% t = [0;0.010;0.030;0.070;0.150];
fileID = fopen('GRONINGEN.vars.txt','r');

for i = 1: length(t)
    str  = ['Time = ' num2str(t(i))];
    while (~feof(fileID))
        s = fgets(fileID);
        if strfind(s, str)
            break;
        end
    end
    if(feof(fileID))
        error('End of File (EOF) found');
    end

fgets(fileID); % skip comment string
%read rest of data
m=fscanf(fileID,'%e');

n = size(m,1)/Var;

f=0:n-1;

pres(i,:) = m(2+f*Var);

fclose(fileID);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [regexp](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to match the line. if it agrees with some match you handle it, otherwise you moveon.

```
fileID = fopen('GRONINGEN.vars.txt','r');
l = getl(fileID)
while ~isnumeric(l)
     if length(regexp(l,'[^\d.]'))==4
         %we have 5 numbers in the line, so we store it
     end
     l = getl(fileID)
end
```